# Move an edge in line with an empty

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I have an arbitrary edge that I would like to move so that it is in line with an arbitrary empty (in this case it will cross over the empty):

[image]

I assume that I will need to perhaps find the translation matrix of the 'line' representing the shortest distance between the edge and the empty but how would I do that using script?

Comment: do you want to do this programmatically or are ways through the interface ok? also are you intending to do this in object mode or edit mode?

Comment: I need to do this programmatically.  Probably in edit mode but for purposes of understanding the translation I don't think it would make too much difference :) --- I'm approaching a solution to the following question but need this translation to test it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32190/multiple-extrude-along-curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have sorted this now using `Vector.project`.  For the script to work one would need to create a 2 vertex edge and call it `line` as well as adding an empty that is renamed `empty` (not `Empty`):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

empty = bpy.data.objects["empty"]
line = bpy.data.objects["line"]

mw = line.matrix_world
ev = empty.location

# get the two line points in world space
lv0 = mw * line.data.vertices[0].co
lv1 = mw * line.data.vertices[1].co

# get the vector of the line
lv = (lv0 - lv1)

# get the translation between the original line and the line vector
# and apply that to the empty location to get the location of the 
# empty relative to the line vector
evt = Matrix.Translation(lv - lv0) * ev

# get the projection of the new empty location onto the line vector
# - `project` gets the perpendicular vector where `evt` intersects `lv`
evp = evt.project(lv)

# get the translation between the projected vector and the empty
tm = Matrix.Translation(evp - evt).inverted()

# now move the line
line.location = tm * line.location
```

I have created a simple [add-on on GitHub](https://github.com/eben-roux/blender-addons/tree/master/move_line_to_empty) to demonstrate the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. Select the edge you want in edit mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>> *Hook to a New Object* and it will create an empty and use its position for the edge.

Edit: Noted the purpose was something different. I'm still not sure you need to do this as a script. Take a look at the curve deformer.